# Formatting date stored in mysql

Tags: mysql, date-format

I am working on a uni project with php and mysql. I have date fields in some of my tables, which have the datatype of 'date'. The default storage of dates is yyyy/mm/dd but i would like it displayed as dd/mm/yyyy. I am trying to select all the fields from 2 of my tables and format a field using the date_format.

I have used the query below, but i am still getting the date output in yyyy/mm/dd.

```
$query="SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(profile.Dob, '%D %M %Y') FROM user, profile WHERE user.Username='$username' and 
user.Password='$password' and user.User_id = profile.User_id";
```

I will also be inserting dates into the datebase through a user form. Will their be similar procedures to go through? Thanks for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 2):

The date is likely being returned twice in your query because you are SELECTING * so the DOB field will be returned twice in your query. Once formatted and once not.

If you must keep the `SELECT *` (usually a 'worst practice') then modify your query as follows and reference the field as formattedDOB

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(profile.Dob, '%D %M %Y') as formattedDOB 
FROM user, profile 
WHERE user.Username='$username' and 
user.Password='$password' and user.User_id = profile.User_id
```

Comment: Would you recommend me to list all the fields instead of using '*' after 'SELECT'?

Comment: Yes. It is generally considered a best practice to list the exact fields you need, even if it turns out to be all of them. More often than not you will find that you don't need all of them anyway.